# Is there a faster way to hijack helicopters?

Tags: just-cause-2

When an enemy helicopter hovers over me, and I grapple on to it, I have to go through a small quick time event to hijack the helicopter. Is there a faster way to take control of enemy helicopters? Going through this routine takes a few seconds to do, and it gets old after a while.

For some boats, I can just shoot both the gunner and the pilot and instantly take control. Is this kind of thing possible with other military vehicles, or am I forced to go through the motions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you mentioned, the only other way to commandeer any vehicles that I'm aware of (helicopters included) is by shooting the driver and jumping in. In the case of a helicopter, it's certainly possible to shoot them, but difficult if you're trying to kill them while grappled below the cockpit. I confirmed this on an attack chopper, in which case I had to shoot the cockpit glass several times before it fell away, at which point I killed the pilot.